# Does reconfiguring mysql delete all the previous databases?

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu-10.04

I am running Ubuntu 10.04.02 and running MySQL 5.1 on it.

Due to some problems i had in restarting the mysql server, the mysql.sock file was deleted.

I looked up this issue and found a link which said that i could reconfigure my MySQL installation, reset the passwords and everything will be good as new.

The thing i'm worried about is, will reconfiguring MySQL delete all the databases i had before.

Comment: I am also facing some issue with MySQL and I am planning to reconfigure it rather than reinstalling it. Just want to make sure does your databases remains after you reconfigure it ? And Is this the command `sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.X` you used ? where x is version of mysql. Now I am running version 5.6.24 so command will be `sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.6.24`. Am I right ?

Comment: Yes, that should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I re-configured my database before and never lost anything.

Saying that, I wasn't particularly worried about it since I took backups of everything beforehand.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response James.

Actually, i can't access the database anymore, so backing up wasn't an option!! :\

Comment: Apparently restarting MySQL will recreate mysql.sock http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/85860

Comment: i'm running the command:

dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.0

its okay, rite??

Answer (score 1):

I have been reconfiguring database for many times during one day and nothing has gone. You can make backup of database before reconfiguring it.